# Who added a drive to my pc?

Tags: drive-letter, logical-drive, boot-partition

One day I noticed a new K drive in my computer (Windows7). if I try to delete the files in that drive it says that the file is in use.

I scanned it with a few antivirus programs, it came back ok.

I'm just wondering what this partition is, and how it got there.

[image]

[image]

Comment: A little more info would be helpful.... Is the computer part of a corporate network?

Comment: let me guess, it's size is 100MB?

Comment: No... its 99.9MB :) from that 81.8 is free. what is it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The size (99.9 MB) suggests it's the system partition Windows creates automatically during installation.
Edit: yep, the Disk Management screenshot you posted would seem to confirm this.

You can hide it from Computer by removing the drive letter. Open Disk Management (type **diskmgmt.msc** into the Start menu search box), right-click on the drive, select "Change Drive Letter and Paths" and in the window that pops up, click on **Remove**.

Comment: +1 exactly what I thought, but I had no idea how to actually hide it.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to figure that out is to go into your system hardware settings and run the Disk Manager software to figure what the drive is.

To hide the drive, which could be a 'system restore partiion' or something similar, I think there is a Windows Explorer option/preference setting to hide drives of a certain type.  You may have inadvertantly changed this setting without realizing it.

Comment: I added the disk management screen

Comment: I should have got this answer but I am glad you figured it out.